# about SearchBar filter from database

Tags: swift

I have built data in Data so like this:
[image]

Hier is the problem: <--
"Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ModleData' and 'String'"

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
var isSearching=false
var tableData=[ModleData]()
var filteredData=[ModleData]()


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }else{
        isSearching = true
        filteredData=tableData.filter({$0 == searchBar.text!})<--
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your following line of code:

```
filteredData=tableData.filter({$0 == searchBar.text!})
```

with this line:

```
filteredData=tableData.filter({$0.name == searchBar.text!})
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing different Type objects **'ModleData' and 'String'"**, comparision operator (==) can be applied to same type objects.

Change this line

```
filteredData=tableData.filter({$0 == searchBar.text!})<--
```

To, this

```
filteredData=tableData.filter({$0.name == searchBar.text!})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter on one of the properties of your model.

```
filteredData = tableData.filter { $0.name == searchBar.text! }
```

Note: better to is !text.isEmpty

```
if let searchText = searchBar.text, !searchText.isEmpty {
    filteredData = tableData.filter { $0.name == searchText }
} else {

}
```